# При заходе в корзину (битрикс) - пустота

Tags: битрикс, order, корзина

Не могу понять - что-то поменял и теперь когда заходишь в корзину, вместо неё пустота. Хотя если зайти в код, то там должно быть хотя бы призыв - заполните корзину и ожидайте когда наши менеджеры с вами свяжутся..... По всей видимости не тот элемент активен и он перебивает, но туплю над решением....

```
   <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Оформление заказа");?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "aspro:basket.scorp", 
    "order", 
    array(
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "order",
        "PATH_TO_CATALOG" => "/catalog/",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO"
    ),
    false
);?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

[image: ,]

Answer (score 0):

Просто имеется шаблон пустой корзины. А есть нужная кнопка "оформить заказ". Соответственно удалить ненужную и радоваться.